# Best practices when using drawRect

Tags: objective-c, uikit, core-graphics

I have recently started creating my own controls and I seem to have a bit of trouble understanding how I should use drawRect.

Basically I have 3 Questions.

1. Is it a good idea to have conditional drawRect's? ie. different drawing code based on properties or instance variables.
2. What is the best method for animating changes to the drawRect's drawing? For example, a fuel gauge control with animated fill and un-fill.
3. And, finally, the examples I have seen for animating with drawRect tend to use timers, is that really a good method in practice? It seems like the heavier apps would have issues with that method.

I guess a 4th would be, is there, perhaps, a better place to do this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it a good idea to have conditional drawRect's? ie. different drawing code based on properties or instance variables.

Sure, why not? If your `drawRect:` method becomes unwieldy, you could split it into multiple methods that you then call from `drawRect:` depending on the properties of your view. E.g. you could have methods like `drawBackground`, `drawTitle`, etc.

> What is the best method for animating changes to the drawRect's drawing? For example, a fuel gauge control with animated fill and un-fill.

That depends. For very small views, you could call `setNeedsDisplay` from a timer, but for larger views, you'll often run into performance issues with this approach.

Animating changes is often better done by compositing your view out of multiple subviews or layers that can be animated with Core Animation (or the simplified `UIView` animation methods).

Comment: "Animating changes is often better done by compositing your view out of multiple subviews or layers that can be animated with Core Animation (or the simplified UIView animation methods)." Could you point me to some examples of this?

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for. There's lots of material about animation on iOS out there. How exactly you'd combine the different techniques depends on the nature of your custom view. E.g. for a simple progress bar, you could get away with just changing the size of the "bar" subview (which can typically be hardware-accelerated), instead of redrawing the entire view, including the static background every time the progress changes...

Comment: I guess I am just having problems planning it out in my head, I guess that's what pencils and paper are for. Thank you very much for your help.